# Append error Detail to every Fault returned by WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

What I'm trying to achieve is to format following response message:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/fault</a:Action>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:To>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <faultcode xmlns:a="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">a:FailedAuthentication</faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="de-DE">Mindestens ein Sicherheitstoken in der Nachricht konnte nicht validiert werden.</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <myCustonDetail>
                ...
                </myCustonDetail>
            </detail>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I know that I can use FaultContract and IErrorHandler to achieve this, however this handles only scenario when exception is thrown within service method itself. But the exception are also raised before service method get called (during checking Message Security etc.) Then by default the message without detail part is returned.

Unfortunately to fulfil some standard requirements I need to append detailed information for every Fault response. Is it possible in .NET? (without writing own implementation of WS-* security standards which I have to use)

Comment: Check out the `IErrorHandler` interface which you can implement on your WCF service class. [See this CodeProject article for an intro](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/801898/WCF-Global-Exception-Handling-using-IErrorHandler)

Comment: As I wrote in my question IErrorHandler does not allow to handle exceptions thrown before service method is called.